How to convert Google My Maps map to Google Maps list
I have a Google My Maps map that I would like to convert to a Google Maps list (such as this one).
It is worth noting that Google My Maps has a feature that allows exporting a map into KML or KMZ file [pic], but I did not find an complemetary feature in Google Maps that allows importing a list.
